# Zoho email limitations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, sendmail, zoho

I´m testing some confirmation emails in my development environment while developing a Rails app. The emails are sent to different email accounts (zoho and gmail accounts) from a zoho account. Everything was working ok, I have done many tests today, but suddenly (without any change), I have stopped receiving new emails. The logs still looks good.

See the summarized logs:

```
Sent mail to business@yanpy.com (2150.1ms)
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 18:09:13 +0200
From: Yanpy <business@yanpy.com>
To: Yanpy <business@yanpy.com>
Message-ID: <53b58029827cb_242d2d6ebcc402cc@ubuntu.mail>
Subject: El usuario cliente.yanpy@gmail.com ha enviado la solicitud de reserva
 [FJGLZLFW] a propietario.yanpy@gmail.com.
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_53b58028802be_242d2d6ebcc400c0";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_53b58028802be_242d2d6ebcc400c0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_53b58029798a3_242d2d6ebcc401a8";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_53b58029798a3_242d2d6ebcc401a8
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Yanpy

Hola Admin,
-----------

El usuario cliente.yanpy@gmail.com ha enviado la solicitud
de reserva [FJGLZLFW] del barco Barquito de papel de
propietario.yanpy@gmail.com.

Un saludo,

El equipo de Yanpy.
----==_mimepart_53b58029798a3_242d2d6ebcc401a8
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

I´m not sure it´s zoho problem, but I think it´s related to it. Is there any limitation of emails received or send from an account in a day. I have done many tests today.

There are several guys working on local environments and the email service has stopped working for all of them.

Thanks,
Roberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

I´m using Amazon SES as email service. I have reached the 200 emails sent limit per day.